# On attach a database I get malformed database schema

Tags: sqlite, centos

I can connect with the database from Java `(JDBC)` but when I try to connect by shell, I get this error:

```
sqlite> attach database "databse.sqlite" as sm;
Error: malformed database schema (VIEW_CALLS) - near "(": syntax error
```

My shell command is:

```
attach database databse.sqlite as db1;
```

Comment: Are you using an older version of the sqlite3 shell than the sqlite3 library used by jdbc? In particular, something older than 3.25 vs that or newer? And does your database include a view that uses window functions?

Comment: I'm updated de sqlite versión to 3.7 on Centos
The maven dependency to jdbc library is:

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
   <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>3.27.2.1</version>
  </dependency>